# if possible that run a php tag in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
           function mehdi()
           {
               alert('salam');
              <?php 
               echo'hi';
               ?>

             }

</script>
this is html:
      <input type="button" name ="submit" value="submit" onclick= "mehdi()">
```

if ehco will execute in this code?
if no how can i run it?

Comment: and you will get a syntax error

Comment: You need a PHP enabled webserver. And you have to echo javascript instructions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The PHP will run on your server before it is sent to the browser, so the browser will receive the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function mehdi()
       {
          alert('salam');
          hi
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
           function mehdi()
           {
               alert('<?php echo "hi";?>');
            }

</script>
```

that should run

Answer (score 0):

The right way is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
           function mehdi()
           {
               alert("<?='hi';?>");
            }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the server you are using is running PHP it should run. Typical innstall Apache, PHP and MySQL with XAMPP for windows. The PHP script will be run automaticaly.

The script should be in a file with .php extention.

```
<?php
$pageTitle = 'Mypage';
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
       function mehdi()
       {
           alert('<?php echo $pageTitle ;?>');
        }

</script>
```